# Is it possible to finalize / release a Class instance?

Tags: java, class, jvm

> It may because the wrong keywords I used, not much discussion or articles found for this problem.

After loaded into JVM, is it possible to release a `Class` instance automatically or manually?

- If it can be released automatically, when will this procedure be executed? Can we expect a certain time point for that?
- If it can be released manually, how? Are there some APIs?
- If it can be released no matter automatically or mannually, are we able to monitor the finalization of `Class` instances, even by using some external tools outside JVM?

Some old articles said that, if

- there is no reference to any instance / static member of a `Class`
- its `ClassLoader` instance is released

that `Class` will be released. Is it working for recent JVMs (for example, Oracle VM 17 or GraalVM 17)? Does it means we are able to construct some `Class` for instant use and have no worry about mem-leak?

```java
class CustomClassLoader extends java.lang.ClassLoader
{
    public CustomClassLoader()
    {
        super(CustomClassLoader.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public Class<?> loadBytes(byte[] bytecode)
    {
        return defineClass(null, bytecode, 0, bytecode.length);
    }
}

@SneakyThrows
Object testMethod()
{
    // read a Class from bytecode by a local ClassLoader
    byte[] bytecode = readSomeBytesFromSomewhere();
    var cl = new CustomClassLoader();
    Class<?> classTest = cl.loadBytes(bytecode);

    // any random code
    return classTest.getMethod("testMethodInClass").invoke(null);
}

public static void main(String... args)
{
    for(int step = 0; step < 9999; step++)
        testMethod();
}
```

For code above, can we consider any resource used by `classTest` will be released everywhen `testMethod` is done because its `ClassLoader` local variable `cl` is never used again?

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: When you use Java 17, don’t use a `CustomClassLoader` for this use case but something like [`var lookup = MethodHandles.lookup().defineHiddenClass(bytecode, true); return lookup.findStatic(lookup.lookupClass(), "testMethodInClass", MethodType.methodType(Object.class)) .invoke();`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#defineHiddenClass(byte%5B%5D,boolean,java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup.ClassOption...)). This class can get garbage collected right after use without depending on class loader reachability.

Comment: Important for controlled destruction of sensitive data bound to a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For code above, can we consider any resource used by classTest will be released everywhen testMethod is done because its ClassLoader local variable cl is never used again?

No, but I think you're mixing terms here. Specifically, any **resource**, no. Resource has a very specific meaning. will it neccessarily be **released**? No. Again, specific meaning.

So let me try to be specific:

### Released? I think you mean Collectable

If the object created by `cl.loadBytes` is garbage collectable (and from the code you showed above, it is), **and** all instances of it are collectable (trivially true in your example; you make no instances), **and** the ClassLoader object is collectable (again, in yoru code, it is), then and only then will it all be collectable.

Does that mean it'll instantly disappear? No, that is not how the garbage collector works. **If** the collector thinks it is necessary to do so, it'll garbage collect. If the collector does not find it neccessary, it won't. It doesn't matter to you - garbage has no effect just by existing.

Point is, your JVM won't throw an OutOfMemoryError because you have 10,000 copies of that `Class` object filling up your memory.

"Released" is a word that is only used in official parlance for resources. See next section.

### Resource? I think you mean Object

A resource is any object that represents a concept at the OS/Architecture level which *must therefore be **manually** closed* in order to **release** this resource.

An example of a 'resource' is `new FileInputStream`. That is an object that is a resource - **you do not rely on the garbage collector to clean this up**, because the garbage collector is free to decide that this particular object needs to be cleaned up many 5 days from now. If there's plenty of heap, why bother. This isn't academic - that really happens. Hence, **do not**, ever, open resource objects without using `try-with-resources` (or loading them in an object that itself `implements AutoClosable`, so that the user of your code can do so). It's the only safe way.

This is called 'releasing'.

What you're asking about is related to resources and releasing resources the same way guns and related to grandmas: Not - at - all.

If you want to use a resource, you use try-with:

```
// bad:

void foo() throws IOException {
  var in = new FileInputStream(...);
  // do stuff with 'in'
  in.close();
}

// good:

void foo() throws IOException {
  try (var in = new FileInputStream(...)) {
    // do stuff with 'in
  }
}
```

ClassLoader shenanigans don't change that at all. It is not possible to 'automatically release' resources without using try-with or manually rolling out a try/finally loop.

Comment: (I'm not native English speaker and feel sorry for those existing and upcoming incorrect usage of words)  
Yes, what I want to ask is whether a `Class` instance and all memory used by that `Class` are collectable. Thanks for the answer above!

Comment: Hey, the only way to fully avoid using the 'wrong' jargon is to read the JLS front-to-back. It's why I went into some depth on a few things, because I had the feeling there was some confusion about the words use. So, fortunately, yeah - it's collectable :)

Comment: It's really a long document. I read some parts of it but haven't fully read it before. Anyway, thanks for you advice.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean: "You should really read it". I meant: "It is a long document that nobody expects you to read, nor should you - hence, jargon confusion will always happen a little bit, nothing to worry about" :)